# Not so popular web : Change Domain and Web Name, SEO implications. Duplicate?

Tags: seo, domains, pagerank

I have owned a site for two years, but never become popular. Today Google income from "clicks" is almost nothing. So I started to redesign the site: more features, a cooler design, and more data.  I also bought a better domain name for this site.

What you you would suggest

1. Redirect from old domain? (like 30 unique visitors per day from Google search :/ )
2. Start from scratch and forget about the "old" one.

I don't  want to be "detected" as duplicate content. But it's possible that my actual site is penalized.

I will post my site is allowed in a future edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, use 301 redirects or Google's canonical URL meta tag.  This way, you will not waste your existing pagerank (even if it is 0, it would still have some internal value depending on the existing backlinks, as compared to a fresh site with no backlinks) and ensure that your new site will almost instantly appear in search results.

Once your new site is more established, you can decide whether to drop the old domain (whether its worth maintaining, etc).

Comment: There is no less then zero. Undiscovered pages have a PR of exactly 0. Once a page is discovered and indexed it is immediately assigned PR as all pages have PR by default. The amount then changes based on link popularity.

Comment: @John Conde Undiscovered and even many discovered pages are `unranked`, not PR 0. My site, even though indexed, showed `unranked` status for a long time. See discussions like  http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=722225  . My personal experience is PR 0 is 'higher' than 'unranked' as far as SERPs are concerned (all else being equal). I am not saying 'better' - because `unranked` may mean google has not assigned anything yet and you may end up getting PR > 0 soon.

Comment: I agree that PR is continuos (internally in Google's algorithm) and bucketized into 0 to 10 only externally - hence all PR 0 pages are not equal, etc. All I am saying is `unranked` is one of the status. Maybe my "less than 0" thing is misleading.

Comment: Every page that is indexed has a PR greater then 0.  All pages, even those that do not appear in the SERPs or rank well, have PR greater then 0. Only undiscovered pages or pages with a penalty can have a PR of 0.

Comment: You are talking about Google's internal ranking algorithms, where the points assigned to a website will be in a much broader range (not 0 to 10), while most end-users (for simplicity) might be thinking in steps: PR 0 is PR 0 for them as shown by the toolbar.

Comment: Any reason why you think the range is not 0 - 10? The formula is published so I don't know how or why it would go beyond 10.

Comment: I think we are not understanding each other's terminology. Initially, you said "Every page that is indexed has a PR greater then 0". That is clearly not true literally. There are millions (perhaps billions?) of pages which are indexed and have a PR of 0 as shown by the toolbar. So, the only interpretation I could make is you were talking that internally, Google assigns points which are in a continous spectrum (not just  a value between 0 to 10) to every page. This definitely has to be the case, given that PR importance is exponential. Not all pages with PR 0 have the same internal points.

Comment: And what I mean by "not in the range of 0 to 10" is - Its a no brainer to see that all billions of pages on the internet cannot possibly fall into one of the 11 rankings (0 to 10). So the internal ranking points would definitely be normalized and relative and have a much larger range, which would then be mapped to PR of 0 to 10.